# Set applicationname in launchsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I tried to set application name in the environment variable for the asp.net core application from launchsettings.json but when an instance is created for WebApplication Builder the application name is reflected in builder.Environment.ApplicationName

I tried setting application name as below in launchsettings.json . The environment is getting reflected but not application name

`"environmentVariables": { "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging", "ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONNAME": "new-app" }`

Answer (score 0):

Assembly names seem to corrupt environment variables, invalidating env-var. You can directly change the name of the assembly.

In `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>new-app</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Test Result:

```
Console.WriteLine(builder.Environment.ApplicationName);
```

[image]

Comment: This method works but my requirement is to get the application name from laucnchsettings.json or from other configuration files

Comment: I tried changing like this: `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions{ Args = args, ApplicationName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_APPLICATIONNAME")});`, but when not changing the name of the assembly, it reports an error, when changing the name of the assembly also to `new-app`, the error disappears.

Comment: So I say the assembly is destroying the environment variable.

Comment: Not sure then how to pass the application name from configuration file and override assembly settings